# registering new service ID error in developer site when implementing apple login with firebase

Tags: ios, firebase

I am implementing `sign in with Apple` with firebase.

I found some problem registering new service ID in `developer.apple.com`

However, when I try to register new service ID with the same bundle identifier with iOS App that I'm trying to implement Apple login, it returns this error in the image.

[image]

**Does service ID has to be different from App bundle Idenfier?**

Comment: If you are implementing Sign In with Apple in an iOS application, then you don't need service id. And we only create bundle identifier on developer.apple.com not service id.

Comment: @Rameez This is about using Firebase Apple Login, not just apple login.

Comment: Yes i am also talking about Firebase Apple login. There is Service ID mentioned on firebase docs which says "The Services ID is used as the web application identifier. It is equivalent to an OAuth client ID" and its not required for iOS.